# How to remove a SpannableString in EditText by EditText.getSelectionStart()

Tags: spannablestring

just like implement del button function

How to remove a SpannableString in EditText by EditText.getSelectionStart()

```
private void enterExpression(String imageFile) {
    try {
        Field field = R.drawable.class.getDeclaredField(imageFile);
        int resourceId = Integer.parseInt(field.get(null).toString());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                resourceId);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(bitmap);

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("[/"
                + imageFile + "]");
        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        sendContentEdt.append(spannableString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtils.e(TAG, "enterExpressionException:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. the simply way is to call del button function as you said.

You may use code as follow:

```
final KeyEvent keyEventDown = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
mEdit.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, keyEventDown);
```

1. Also, you may deal with the `SpannableString` and reassign it to the editText. you only need to work out whether it is a char or an imagespan before the position `=EditText.getSelectionStart();` Since your imagespane Strings are quoted in "[]", you remove all the char between "[" and "]",including them.

there are some sample code:

```
StringBuffer localStringBuffer = new StringBuffer(mEdit.getText().toString());
int i,j;
String result;
if (localStringBuffer.length() > 0) {
    i = cursor;
    if (i != 0) {
        char ch = localStringBuffer.charAt(i - 1);
        if (localStringBuffer.charAt(i - 1) != ']') {
            result = localStringBuffer.toString().substring(0, i - 1) + localStringBuffer.toString().substring(i);
            j = i-1;
        }else{
            j =localStringBuffer.substring(0, i - 1).lastIndexOf("[");
            if(j==-1) j =i;
            result = localStringBuffer.toString().substring(0, j) + localStringBuffer.toString().substring(i);
        }
        mEdit.setText(addSmileySpansFromCode(result));
        mEdit.setSelection(j);
    }
}
```